# Couldn't resolve a key not in index error

Tags: python-3.x, regex, tabula

[This is the link to the pdf file from which I want to extract data](https://www.aai.aero/sites/default/files/traffic-news/Mar202kAnnex2.pdf)

```
def onlyenglish(text):
    import re
    alphabet_regular_expression = re.compile("[^a-zA-Z|()]")
    text = re.sub(alphabet_regular_expression,"",text)
    return text
    
annexure2page1 =  tabula.read_pdf(file, pages = 1 , lattice = True, relative_area=True)
annexure2page1_df1= annexure2page1[0]
annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df1[['एयिपोर्च\rAIRPORT','वायुयाि प्रर्ालि (संख्या में)\rAIRCRAFT MOVEMENTS (IN NOS.)','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 8','Unnamed: 10']]
annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df2.replace('\r',' ', regex=True)`

annexure2page1_df2['ReportMonth'] = reportmonth
annexure2page1_df2['एयरपोर्\rAIRPORT'] = annexure2page1_df2['एयरपोर्\rAIRPORT'].str.title()
annexure2page1_df2['Airports'] = annexure2page1_df2['एयरपोर्\rAIRPORT'].apply(lambda x: onlyenglish(str(x)))
annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df2.rename(columns={'वरयुयरन प्रचरलन (िंख्यर म )\rAIRCRAFT MOVEMENTS (IN NOS.)':'value','Unnamed: 8':'value_ytm','Unnamed: 4':'value_smly','Unnamed: 10':'value_ytmly'})
annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df2.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)

annexure2page1_df3 = annexure2page1_df2.dropna()
annexure2page1_df3["Service"] = "International"
annexure2page1_df3["Metric"] = "ATMs"
annexure2page1_df3['ReportName'] = reportname
annexure2page1_df3['reportlink'] = file
##extracting page 1
annexure2page1extraction = annexure2page1_df3[['ReportName','reportlink','ReportMonth','Airports','Service','Metric','value','value_smly','value_ytm','value_ytmly']]
```

**Error Stack**

```
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-9c5d09fa538a> in <module>()
      2 annexure2page1_df1= annexure2page1[0]
      3 #
----> 4 annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df1[['एयिपोर्च\rAIRPORT','वायुयाि प्रर्ालि (संख्या में)\rAIRCRAFT MOVEMENTS (IN NOS.)','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 8','Unnamed: 10']]
      5 annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df2.replace('\r',' ', regex=True)
      6 annexure2page1_df2['ReportMonth'] = reportmonth

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1302             if raise_missing:
   1303                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1304                 raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
   1305 
   1306             # we skip the warning on Categorical

KeyError: "['वायुयाि प्रर्ालि (संख्या में)\\rAIRCRAFT MOVEMENTS (IN NOS.)', 'एयिपोर्च\\rAIRPORT'] not in index"
```

Comment: Someone, could you please help me about not in index error I am getting it for many pdfs. please help!

Comment: I am trying to select it through specific columns by iloc any idea how to perform it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line of code -->
`annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df1[['एयिपोर्च\rAIRPORT','वायुयाि प्रर्ालि (संख्या में)\rAIRCRAFT MOVEMENTS (IN NOS.)','Unnamed: 4','Unnamed: 8','Unnamed: 10']]`

with --> `annexure2page1_df2 = annexure2page1_df1.iloc[:,[3,5,7,11,13]]`

The error that you got ( `KeyError: "['वायुयाि प्रर्ालि (संख्या में)\\rAIRCRAFT MOVEMENTS (IN NOS.)', 'एयिपोर्च\\rAIRPORT'] not in index"`) is becuase of keys not found.

So , I have bypassed it by directly providing the index location of the columns that you want to subset.
[Check out the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6xoo.png)

Comment: Hi, I have used index to select the rows and my code got executed but the output is only giving columns names. The output needed is with the values in each columns but at last tine when I am putting 'value' key then its showing key not in index. Please tell me how to get values.

Comment: the last tine of code is throwing error--> 'annexure2page1extraction = annexure2page1_df3[['ReportName','reportlink','ReportMonth','Airports','Service','Metric','value','value_smly','value_ytm','value_ytmly']]'